# Printing with commas in python

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it was possible to add commas to numbers, with a for loop similar to this

```
for x in range(0,10):
    print x
```

the output I am looking for is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may simply do it in 1 line as :

```
",".join(map(str, range(10)))
```

where, `join()` method is used to concatenate the strings with the given character `","` (in this case) and `map()` converts each integer from `range(10)` to type `str`.

Alternatively, if you want to use `for` loop then you may simply concatenate the string using `+` between the `str(i)` and the `","`.

```
for i in range(10):
     print str(i) + ",",
```

Comment: but that will give me '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9', I don't want the ' ' I just want 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: @Engah - Do `a = ",".join(map(str, range(10)))` and then `print a`. :P The quotes `''` indicate that it is a string they won't be included when you say write it in a file.

Comment: what if it's a list like L = [1,2,3,4,5] is there a way I could get rid of the [ ]? so then it would print 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: `a = ",".join(map(str, L))` and you get string without `[ ]`

Comment: then replace the `range(10)` by `L` as : `",".join(map(str, L))`

Comment: @Engah: Check [the `str.join()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [the `map()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you may do it in one line:

```
print(*range(10),sep=',')
```

Result:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
start = 0
end = 10
result = ""
for x in range(start,end+1):
   result += str(x)
   if x < (end):
        result += ","
print(result) # $: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
```